# Create doctrine association on database field with concatenated IDs

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a Symfony 2 / Doctrine 2 application on top of an existing MySQL database. Due to poor decisions in the past, i'm stuck with references that are concatenated in a table-column. Unfortunately remodeling the database is not an option.

E.g. entity "Product" referring to multiple "Categories":

```
| id | name      | category_ids |
|----|-----------|--------------|
| 1  | product a | 1,2,5        |
| 2  | product b | 3,4,1        |
| 3  | product c | 2            |
```

I would like to have the method `getCategories` available in my "Product" entity which would return a Collection of Category objects.

Is there any way to achieve this with Doctrine?

Maybe use custom code that is based on "FIND_IN_SET"?

```
SELECT c.* 
  FROM product p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN category c ON FIND_IN_SET(c.id, p.category_ids)
  WHERE p.id=:product_id;
```

Or maybe define the association with exploded values?

```
explode(',',$this->category_ids)
```

I try to avoid having to use the EntityManager each time i need to retrieve Categories from my Product entity. Because:

- Injecting the EntityManager in Entities is bad practice
- Using the EntityManager each time in my controllers a bit against the DRY-principle
- I have no idea how to achieve this in Symfony FormTypes to have a Choice/Entity field with the relevant Categories for a Product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can make a hydration strategy for your `getCategories` method and register this strategy inside your hydrator class (could even be `DoctrineObject` hydrator). Something like:

**Strategy**

```
<?php

namespace My\Hydrator\Strategy;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use My\Entity\Category;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Persistence\ObjectManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\Strategy\StrategyInterface;

class CategoriesStrategy implements StrategyInterface, ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $objectManager
     * @param String $hostName
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $value
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function extract($value)
    {
        $collection = new ArrayCollection();

        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $id) {
                $category = $this->getObjectManager()->find(Category::class, $id);
                $collection->add($category);
            }
        }

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $value
     * @return array
     */
    public function hydrate($value)
    {
        $array = array();
        /** @var Category $category */
        foreach ($value as $category) {
            $array[] = $category->getId();
        }
        return $array;
    }

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $objectManager
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return ObjectManager
     */
    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->objectManager;
    }
}
```

You probably need a factory to register your `CategoriesStrategy` inside your hydrator class:

**Hydrator Factory**

```
<?php

namespace My\Hydrator;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject;
use My\Hydrator\Strategy\CategoriesStrategy;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class MyHydratorFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return DoctrineObject
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        /** @var ServiceManager $serviceManager */
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

        /** @var ObjectManager $objectManager */
        $objectManager = $serviceManager->get('bc_object_manager');

        /** @var DoctrineObject $hydrator */
        $hydrator = new DoctrineObject($objectManager);
        $hydrator->addStrategy('categories', new CategoriesStrategy($objectManager));
        return $hydrator;
    }
}
```

This is not tested, but you get the idea...

---

### Solution 2

Another solution would be to register a DBAL type for your categories. You can check on how to do this in [the Doctrine2 documentation chapter 8.4. Custom Mapping Types](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types).

In your entity column definition you point to a categories type:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="categories")
 */
protected $categories;
```

And the magic you register in doctrine like this:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'types' => array(
                'categories' => 'My\DBAL\Types\CategoriesCollection '
            )
        )
    )
)
```

And then the class itself:

```
<?php

namespace My\DBAL\Types;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

class CategoriesCollection extends \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type
{
    const NAME = 'categories';

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getDoctrineTypeMapping('simple_array');
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return array
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $array = [];
        foreach($value as $category)
        {
            $category_id = $category->getId();
            array_push($array, $category_id);
        }
        return $array;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $collection = new ArrayCollection();
        if ($value === null) {
            return $collection;
        }

        foreach($value as $category_id){
            $category = $this->em->getReference('Vendor\Bundle\Entity\Category', $category_id);
            $collection->add($category);
        }

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;


    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }
}
```

This solution is virtually the same as the other solution only you use the Doctrine2 internals to get there. You will still need to register the `EntityManager` in your DBAL type and not sure what is the easiest way, so that I leave up to you.

In Symfony you can register the Custom Mapping Type in your app/config/config.yml file

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    types:
      category_ids: Vendor\Bundle\Type\CategoriesCollection
```

You can than inject the EntityManager dependency in the boot sequence of your bundle:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Bundle\Bundle;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Trilations\TApp\CoreBundle\Type\CategoryCollectionType;

class VendorBundleBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
        $categoryCollectionType = Type::getType('category_ids');
        $categoryCollectionType->setEntityManager($em);
    }
}
```

And map the field to the correct custom mapping:

```
Vendor\Bundle\Enitity\Product
  table: product
  fields:
    categories: category_ids
```

Comment: Your second solution using Doctrine Custom Mapping worked like a charm. I changed it a bit, in order to use 'string' mapping instead of 'simple array', as this requires using column-comments (and i didn't want to change anything about the DB).

For Symfony users:
- you can register this custom type in your config file (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types)
- and inject the required EntityManager depency through a setter method in your bundle boot-method (http://bit.ly/1LHuCj2)

Comment: @RenaudC. Can you please change/update my answer and add the code for setting the `EntityManager` in the `CategoriesCollection` type class.

Comment: @RenaudC. Thanks for adding that. I will soon add the corresponding code for Zend Framework 2.